# Capture image of a detected face using webcam?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I am new to MATLAB. I need to capture image and save it into a folder. THis is my matlab code for detect face.

```
 % Create the face detector object.
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

% Create the point tracker object.
pointTracker = vision.PointTracker('MaxBidirectionalError', 2);

% Create the webcam object.
cam = webcam();

% Capture one frame to get its size.
videoFrame = snapshot(cam);
frameSize = size(videoFrame);

% Create the video player object.
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [100 100 [frameSize(2), frameSize(1)]+30]);

runLoop = true;
numPts = 0;
frameCount = 0;
%%x = 0;  
while runLoop && frameCount < 400

%% while(x<1)
    % Get the next frame.
    videoFrame = snapshot(cam);
    videoFrameGray = rgb2gray(videoFrame);
    frameCount = frameCount + 1;

    if numPts < 10
        % Detection mode.
        bbox = faceDetector.step(videoFrameGray);

        if ~isempty(bbox)
            % Find corner points inside the detected region.
            points = detectMinEigenFeatures(videoFrameGray, 'ROI', bbox(1, :));

            % Re-initialize the point tracker.
            xyPoints = points.Location;
            numPts = size(xyPoints,1);
            release(pointTracker);
            initialize(pointTracker, xyPoints, videoFrameGray);

            % Save a copy of the points.
            oldPoints = xyPoints;

            % the orientation of the face.
            bboxPoints = bbox2points(bbox(1, :));

            % Convert the box corners into the [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4]
            % format required by insertShape.
            bboxPolygon = reshape(bboxPoints', 1, []);

            % Display a bounding box around the detected face.
            videoFrame = insertShape(videoFrame, 'Polygon', bboxPolygon, 'LineWidth', 3);

            % Display detected corners.
            videoFrame = insertMarker(videoFrame, xyPoints, '+', 'Color', 'white');
        end

    else
        % Tracking mode.
        [xyPoints, isFound] = step(pointTracker, videoFrameGray);
        visiblePoints = xyPoints(isFound, :);
        oldInliers = oldPoints(isFound, :);

        numPts = size(visiblePoints, 1);

        if numPts >= 10
            % Estimate the geometric transformation between the old points
            % and the new points.
            [xform, oldInliers, visiblePoints] = estimateGeometricTransform(...
                oldInliers, visiblePoints, 'similarity', 'MaxDistance', 4);

            % Apply the transformation to the bounding box.
            bboxPoints = transformPointsForward(xform, bboxPoints);

            % Convert the box corners into the [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4]
            % format required by insertShape.
            bboxPolygon = reshape(bboxPoints', 1, []);

            % Display a bounding box around the face being tracked.
            videoFrame = insertShape(videoFrame, 'Polygon', bboxPolygon, 'LineWidth', 3);

            % Display tracked points.
            videoFrame = insertMarker(videoFrame, visiblePoints, '+', 'Color', 'white');

            % Reset the points.
            oldPoints = visiblePoints;
            setPoints(pointTracker, oldPoints);
        end

    end

    % Display the annotated video frame using the video player object.
    step(videoPlayer, videoFrame);

    % Check whether the video player window has been closed.
    runLoop = isOpen(videoPlayer);
end

% Clean up.
clear cam;
release(videoPlayer);
release(pointTracker);
release(faceDetector);
```

Please help me to capture image and save.

I tried this code for capture image and save

```
vid = videoinput('dcam',1,'RGB24_640x480');
preview(vid);
start(vid); 
im=getdata(vid); 
figure,imshow(im); 
write(im,'test1image.jpg');
```

When I try this code it gives and error,

Error using videoinput (line 233)
There are no devices installed for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO.

Error in takeimage (line 1)
vid = videoinput('dcam',1,'RGB24_640x480');

Comment: The problem is ovbious: MATLAB can not detect any camera named `dcam`

Comment: I used 'winvideo' also. It also gives error.

imaqhwinfo

ans = 

    InstalledAdaptors: {'dcam'}
        MATLABVersion: '8.6 (R2015b)'
          ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
       ToolboxVersion: '4.10 (R2015b)'

Comment: What happens when you do videoinput('dcam') ? I cannot recreate your error. Also, try `imaqhwinfo('dcam')` to see what the Device ID is, sometimes it is not 1.

Comment: When I use 'dcam' as a videoinput it shows following error,

Error using videoinput (line 233)
There are no devices installed for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO.

Error in takeimage (line 1)
vid = videoinput('dcam',1,'RGB24_640x480');


This is the device IDs;
>> info=imaqhwinfo('dcam')

info = 

       AdaptorDllName: 'C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2015b\dcamhardware\toolbox\imaq\supportpackages\dcam\adaptor\win64…'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '4.10 (R2015b)'
          AdaptorName: 'dcam'
            DeviceIDs: {1x0 cell}
           DeviceInfo: [1x0 struct]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to download a [support package](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/installing-the-support-packages-for-image-acquisition-toolbox-adaptors.html) for the Image Acquisition Toolbox for your particular camera. If you are using a regular USB webcam, then you probably need the "OS Generic Video Interface" support package.

Comment: Could it be that you do not have a DCAM camera? Can you try installing the "OS Generic Video Interface" support package?

Comment: Thank you for the support. Now I installed "OS Generic Video Interface" . My code is working.